# Multiple text values in one column, need the query to find the most repeatable word

Tags: mysql

I have a column that stores the bio/title of users. It's custom written by users and can have as many words.

```
id title
1  Business Development Executive Cold Calling & Cold Emailing expert Entrepreneur
2  Director of Online Marketing and entrepreneur
3  Art Director and Entrepreneur 
4  Corporate Development at Yahoo!
5  Snr Program Manager, Yahoo
```

I am trying to figure out a mysql query that shows word frequencies:

```
Entrepreneur 3
development  2
director     2
```

I know if I could return each word in the value as a separate row, I could then use normal grouping. I have looked, but can't find, a function that splits text into words each in a separate row.

Can it be done?

Comment: Not easily. SQL isn't terribly well-suited for such a task - you might be better off querying the bios and parsing them in (presumably server-side) code.

Comment: Your design is somewhat flawed. You should have a category table reference to a category ID in your job title table.

Comment: Can someone else please vote to reopen this? I worked out a solution for it, but it was closed before I could post it.

Comment: @Bohemian - You got my vote!:)

Answer (score 4):

You can do it by joining with a manufactured number series that is used to pick out the nth word. Unfortunately, mysql has no built-in method if generating a series, so it's a little ugly, but here it is:

```
select
  substring_index(substring_index(title, ' ', num), ' ', -1) word,
  count(*) count
from job j
join (select 1 num union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9 union select 10 union select 11 union select 12) n
on length(title) >= length(replace(title, ' ', '')) + num - 1
group by 1
order by 2 desc
```

See a [live demo on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/606a0/20) using your data and producing your expected output.

Sadly, the limitation of having to hard code every value of the number series also limits the number of words of the column that will be processed (in this case 12). It doesn't matter if there are too many numbers in the series, and you can always add more to cover a larger expected input text.

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting all job titles and returning it as an array.  Then do something like this in php:

```
<?php
$array = array("Business Development Executive Cold Calling & Cold Emailing expert  Entrepreneur ", "Director of Online Marketing and entrepreneur", "Art Director and Entrepreneur", "Corporate Development at Yahoo!", "Snr Program Manager, Yahoo");
$words = "";
foreach($array as $val) $words .= " ".strtolower($val);
print_r(array_count_values(str_word_count($words, 1)));
?>
```

Will output:

```
Array ( [business] => 1 [development] => 2 [executive] => 1 [cold] => 2 [calling] => 1 [emailing] => 1 [expert] => 1 [entrepreneur] => 3 [director] => 2 [of] => 1 [online] => 1 [marketing] => 1 [and] => 2 [art] => 1 [corporate] => 1 [at] => 1 [yahoo] => 2 [snr] => 1 [program] => 1 [manager] => 1 )
```

Comment: we need to do it not row wise by column wise agregatting all the data in a column then giving the overall count. Please see the example i provided.

Comment: I believe that is exactly what my example does.  I take the array that contains all of the "bio/title" results and combine it with a foreach loop to be one long string.  I then return the array of each individual word used in all "bio/title" entries with the count of how many times they appear.  If that is not what you are asking for please clarify what is wrong/missing.

Comment: wants it in mysql not PHP