# Using MySQL how can I create a list of all words in a set of strings?

Tags: mysql

Let's say I've got a table like this:

```
| RowID | LongString                   |
----------------------------------------
|   1   | This is a really long string | 
|   2   | This is a shorter string     |
```

How can I get a list of distinct words used in all the rows such as below:

```
| Result: |
-----------
| This    |
| is      |
| a       |
| really  |
| long    |
| string  |
| shorter |
```

Comment: Is there a reasonable limit to the number of words per sentence?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple text values in one column, need the query to find the most repeatable word](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19392810/multiple-text-values-in-one-column-need-the-query-to-find-the-most-repeatable-w)

Comment: http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/

Answer (score 0):

From MySQL docs:

> MySQL does not include a function to split a delimited string. Although separated data would normally be split into separate fields within a relation data, spliting such can be useful either during initial data load/validation or where such data is held in a text field.

So there is not ready-to-go solution. If I were you, I would split such string after fetching it from DB (it is easy to do in PHP, Java C# and so on).

Howewer on [**this**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html) site someone has wrote procedure for such task. Check it out. It is in comments section below.

Comment: Might there be any way to do this using stored procedures?